# how to merge pdf page

Tags: pdf

I have one pdf file which is extract from ppt (power point presentation) and one page in pdf is one slide. How can I merge two pdf page in one page.

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[pdftk](http://www.accesspdf.com/pdftk/) is the tool I use

Comment: plus one for pdftk, it runs a native windows exe file which is very fast--unlike java.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.pdfjoin.com/ is an online solution. [Here's](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pdfjoin) the (linux) command line tool.

Answer (score 0):

Quick googling did bring up this tool: http://www.pdfsam.org/

GPL licenced too.